# JQuery: Text changed on previous element disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am working on a JQuery application where I am trying to change the text of a previous element using `$(element).prev().text("Mytext");`. But when I scroll up / scroll down the page, the changes I have made are disappeared.

```
titles = $('.checkGroup:checked').parent().map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
}).get(); // Generate Array of Titles
for (i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    $('span[level ="' + i + '"]').prev().text(titles[i]);
}
```

this is my code snippet. please help me to fix this

Comment: From where `length` comes?

Comment: It is length of titles array. `tites.length`

Comment: You should have mentioned it in your code!

Comment: Can you also post the html?

Comment: go through this link https://preview.c9.io/prem_kumar_e/slickgrid/examples/grouping.html?_c9_id=livepreview3&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io

Comment: How do you recreate the issue in the link? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this add the following JS.

> Note that this is a quick fix. There must be some callback functions you can use to have the same end effect. The `Slick.Grid` plugin is rendering the HTML on scroll. Hence the issue.

Events for **[SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Grid-Events)**.

## Edit 1:

```
grid.onScroll.subscribe(function(e,args){
    $('.checkGroup:checked').parent().each(function (i, val) {
        $('span[level ="' + i + '"]').each(function(){
            $(this).prev().text($(val).text());
        });
    });
})
```

Normally the following might have worked. But the **SlickGrid** had many mysteries of its own. Its not a scroll event.

```
$(document).on('scroll', '.slick-viewport',function(){
    $('.checkGroup:checked').parent().each(function (i, val) {
        $('span[level ="' + i + '"]').each(function(){
            $(this).prev().text($(val).text());
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: @Prem anywhere after you include the jquery file.

Comment: I tried it by replacing the older one with the above but not getting. :( . Please help me

Comment: @Prem do one thing, put the code I provided inside `<script>$(document).ready(function(){ /*here*/})</script>` and try.

Comment: Still no use. if u wish I am ready to share my c9.io workspace with you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88760/discussion-between-rejith-r-krishnan-and-prem).